# Chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation.js difficulty rendering a horizontal line, using Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion, chart.js

I am trying to add a horizontal line to my chart.js bar chart at the 250 mark.  I am have tried both chart.js version 2.6.0 and version 2.7.0 with no success. I am not sure if this is due to me me using data from a cfquery. I have the code added to the bottom of my coldfusion page. I have added my code below.

```
    <html>
      <head>
      <cfparam name="url.urlparam" default="1">
      <cfif url.urlparam GTE 5>
      <cfset url.urlparam = 1>
     <cfelse>
     <cfset url.urlparam = url.urlparam + 1>
     </cfif>

     <script src="../../js/Chart.min.js"></script>
     <title>Data</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"               href="http://wat524.wat.michelin.com/ca3//RestrictedSection   /reportstylesheet.css">
     <script src="../../js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../..                   /css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="../../js/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
     <script src="../../js/Chart-bundle.js"></script>
     <style type="text/css">

     .style1 {color: #000066}
     .style3 {
      color: #009933;
      font-size: 9pt;
      }
     .style18 {color: #3300FF}
     .style19 {
     color: #FF0000;
      font-weight: bold;
     font-size: xx-small;
     }
    .style21 {color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-size: xx-small; }
    .style22 {
    font-size: xx-small;
    color: #339933;
    font-weight: bold;
     }
    .style25 {color: #FF0000}
    .style26 {color: #339933}


    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <cfset ColourChange="0">
    <cfswitch expression="#url.urlparam#">
    <cfcase value="1">
    <cfset ColourChange="##FFFF9D">
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="2">
    <cfset ColourChange="##9CF5F5">
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="3">
    <cfset ColourChange="##F2CCE6">
    </cfcase>
    cfcase value="4">
    <cfset ColourChange="##BFFFDF">
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="5">
    <cfset ColourChange="##FFD1A4">
    </cfcase>
    `enter code here`</cfswitch>


    <div class="container align-items-center">
    <cfoutput>
    <h1 class="display-4"><strong>Total as of #datetimeformat(timestamp, "dd    mmmm yyyy HH:nn")#</strong></h1>
     </cfoutput>
    </div>
   <div class="container align-items-center" style="align:center; width:    1600px; height:400px; inline-block;">
    <canvas name="charttotal" id="charttotal" width="1200" height="600"    ></canvas></div>
   </body>
   </html>
        <script>

        var ctx = document.getElementById("charttotal").getContext('2d');
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
        ctx.lineTo(250, 50);
        ctx.stroke();
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: [
            <cfoutput>
            <cfset step = 0>
            <cfloop query="rstTotalForChart" >
              <cfset step++>"#actual_date#"<cfif step lt 24>,</cfif>
            </cfloop>
          </cfoutput>
        ],
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Total',
              data: [
                <cfoutput>
                <cfset step = 0>
                <cfloop query="rstTotalForChart" >
                  <cfset step++>#prodcount#<cfif step lt 24>,</cfif>
                </cfloop>
              </cfoutput>
            ],
              backgroundColor:
                  'rgba(74, 13, 196, 0.74)',
              borderColor:
                  'rgba(81, 0, 244, 1)',

              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
        tooltipTemplate: "<%= value%>",
        showTooltips: true,
        onAnimationComplete: function()
        {
          this.showTooltips(this.datasets[0].bars, true);
        },
        tooltipEvents:[],
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
      },
      annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: 250,
        borderColor: 'rgb(244, 13, 13)',
        borderWidth: 4,
        label: {
          backgroundColor: "red",
              content: "250",
              enabled: true


        }
      }]
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe if you add the html tag code we can edit and generate a snippet code to execute your code and it will be helpfull to understand the problem and generate an answer

Comment: Thank you, I updated to include my html.